# How can I persuade macOS finder to start when normal methods fail?

Tags: macos, finder

Scenario:

1. Recently re-booted macOS 11.6 (but happens from time to time over last few years). Spinning beach ball in all Finder windows.
2. right-click Finder icon in dock and select Relaunch. Finder windows disappear but don't reopen.
3. Click Finder icon in dock, and little light comes on for 0.5 sec and then turns off. No windows open.
4. Try command line `open .`. Nothing happens.

What else can I try short of rebooting?

Comment: Have you try boot in Safe mode (push shift key at boot)?

Comment: Thanks, @Jean_JD. Thankfully I can reboot OK to fix the situation when it happens, which is thankfully rarely. I was looking for a way that was less nuclear.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a second account on the Mac? I always create one, just in case, for situations like this.

Can you start Terminal.app?

If you have Remote Login enabled, you can `ssh` in and enter:

```
defaults delete com.apple.finder
```

Then reboot:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

and enter your login password when prompted.

Comment: Thanks tj-luoma. Thankfully I can reboot OK to fix the situation when it happens, but this is a useful trick to know.

Answer (score 0):

The spinning cursor in finder is typically a timeout for local attached disks or error condition in storage. Unless you have Finder extensions that involve network (Dropbox, etc…) figuring why Finder is stuck might be key even if a clean restart gets you going again for a while.

Opening Activity Monitor from spotlight is what I would do and look for other processes that might be stuck or indicate an issue. From there, grab a system diagnosis so you have details of what the system state was before restarting.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/activity-monitor/run-system-diagnostics-actmntr2225/mac

Do you typically have the system running for 6 months or more between restarts? A clean start of the OS shouldn’t be considered a nuclear option for most but it would be interesting to learn how you’re set up or why this would be avoided.

Comment: Thanks, @bmike. I only a few weeks at most between reboots.  But since upgrading to Monterey (v12.x) I believe I've not seen this particular failure again.